# Move input between divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Trying to move user input from one div to another via a move button, back and forth. Even if there is multiple inputs one can move selected input from one to the other.
So far it moves all inputs in "field1" to "field2". Im trying to move only a single line back and forth.

Tried various stuff, still learning this. Any pointers on what i need to look at in order to achieve this?`
Any help appreciated.

```js
var number = [];

function myNotes() {
  var x = document.getElementById("field1");
  number.push(document.getElementById("input").value);
  x.innerHTML = number.join('<input type="button" value="move" onclick="move();"/><br/>');
}

function move() {
  $('#field1').appendTo('#field2')
}
```

```css
form {
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <input id="input" type=text>
</form>
<input type=submit onclick="myNotes();" value="Send">

<br>
<span id='displaytitle'></span>
<h2>Field 1</h2>
<div id="field1"></div>
<h2>Field 2</h2>
<div id="field2"></div>
```

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/j5mvq6L5/3/)

Comment: Can you please be a little clearer with what you are attempting to achieve? I cannot tell whether you want move text from the input box into the text of the div, or whether you want to move the divs, or something else.

Comment: Once input is shown in "field1", a move button appears on the right side. Clicking this button moves the text to "field2".

Comment: can't you just make the move button `onclick` do something like: `document.getElementById('field2').innerHTML = document.getElementById('field1').innerHTML` ?

Comment: (or `.innerText` or `.textContent` if you don't want to use `.innerHTML`)

Comment: Yes, but doing so moves all inputs to field, if there are more than 1 that is. Im trying to move only 1 input (out of several) to field2, leaving the rest in field1

Comment: Something like this? https://jsfiddle.net/mwpsdg1p/2/

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, Silsand, please be sure to upvote and accept my answer if I helped you!  That's what keeps this site running.  Thanks!

Comment: It did, thank you for that. Will keep working on this.

Answer (score 2):

You've got a mixture of javascript and jQuery going that's kind of hard to understand.  I've whipped up an example of this using jQuery, since you seem to have it in your project anyway:

https://jsfiddle.net/j5mvq6L5/7/

HTML:

```
<form>
  <input id="input" type=text>
</form>
<input type=submit id="btnSend" value="Send">

<br>
<span id='displaytitle'></span>
<h2>Field 1</h2>
<div id="field1" class="field"></div>
<h2>Field 2</h2>
<div id="field2" class="field"></div>
```

JS:

```
//listen for document ready
$(document).ready(function() { 
    //button click listener:
    $("#btnSend").on("click", function(e) {

        var $field1 = $("#field1");  //works like getElementById

        //create a containing div for later
        var $entry = $("<div></div>").addClass("entry");

        //create a new button
        var $btnMove = $("<input/>").attr("type", "button").attr("value", "move").addClass("btnMove");

        //click listener for the new button
        $btnMove.click(function(){              
          //find "sibling" field (I added a class to both), append this button's parent div
          $(this).parents(".field").siblings(".field").append($(this).parent());
        });

        //append entry parts
        $entry.append($("#input").val())
              .append($btnMove);

        //append entry to #field1
        $field1.append($entry);          
    });
 });
```

CSS:

```
form {
  display: inline;
}

.btnMove {
  margin-left: .5em;
}
```

Comment: This is a much better answer than my attempt. The only things I'd add are for usability (clear & focus input on click).

Comment: I'm at work, so I whipped this up quickly, but good points!  Feel free to update the fiddle, and edit my answer.